# ¿Cómo resaltar un mensaje de error de login PHP?

Tags: php, apache

Quisiera que se resalte este mensaje de error de PHP cada vez que alguien introduzca por error su usuario y/o contraseña:

```
 if($num>0){
        $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        $password_bd = $row['password'];

        $pass_c = sha1($password);

        if($password_bd == $pass_c) {

            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_firma'] = $row['nombre_firma'];


            header("Location: principal.php");

        } else {
            echo "Error de Autenticación.";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Usuario inexistente.";
    }
```

Agradezco su respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Creo que esto es más html y css que PHP

Comment: Si quieres algo que resalte mejor usa un alert, ahora si quieres algo mas resaltante aun puedes usar un alert de jQueryUi o un alert de jAlert 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente lo que hace tu script es mostrar un texto en la página web. Si no indicas nada ese texto usará los estilos por defecto.
Si quieres resaltarlo añade código de estilo.
Declara una clase en CSS y aplícala al texto encerrándolo en un span

```
<style>
.destacar{color:red; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold}
</style>
```

Luego en el código php

```
echo '<span class="destacar">No autorizado</span>'
```

Esto te pone el texto en rojo negrita y grande.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió este método. Buen día.